# Ubuntu - Removing MPFR and installing a new version from source

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am on Ubuntu Hardy Heron trying to compile gcc 4.4 from source. The problem is that I need MPFR version 2.3.2 or greater. I have MPFR version 2.3.1. I can verify this via running this small snippet of C code obtained from their [site](http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Installing-MPFR)-:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <mpfr.h>

  int main (void)
  {
   printf ("MPFR library: %-12s\nMPFR header:  %s (based on %d.%d.%d)\n",
              mpfr_get_version (), MPFR_VERSION_STRING, MPFR_VERSION_MAJOR,
              MPFR_VERSION_MINOR, MPFR_VERSION_PATCHLEVEL);
   return 0;
}

cc -o version version.c -lmpfr -lgmp
```

This prints out-:

```
MPFR library: 2.3.1       
MPFR header:  2.3.2 (based on 2.3.2)
```

I have downloaded and built MPFR(version 2.3.2) from source and it has installed correctly in /usr/local, but the problem is that gcc won't link to it by default. I have to use the following compilation options to link to my new MPFR library -:

```
gcc test_mpfr.o -o test_mpfr -Wl,-Bstatic -l:/usr/local/lib/libmpfr.a -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

This produces the correct and expected output of -:

```
MPFR library: 2.3.2       
MPFR header:  2.3.2 (based on 2.3.2)
```

Now my questions is that

*firstly how do I remove my default MPFR installation* from my system (**apt-get --purge remove libmpfr-dev does nothing**), and

*secondly how do I make my new MPFR installation my default one so that gcc can link to it automatically.*

Answer (score 0):

---

Removing the system gcc, mpfr is not a good idea. Please reinstall. (`sudo apt-get install g++`) And : You can have as many versions of gcc as you want, installed at the same time. The default compilers for Hardy : `sudo apt-get install g++ g++-3.3 g++-3.4 g++-4.1` ,,, where g++ is the system compiler gcc/g++ version 4.2.4 .

Compilers, **gcc44, g++44 are available** for Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy, example i386 : {gcc44_4.4.7-2_i386.deb, gcc44-c++_4.4.7-2_i386.deb, libstdc++44-devel_4.4.7-2_i386.deb} . Links :

gcc44 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNYmpYeGZHS0RUR0U/view?usp=sharing
gcc44-c++ https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNMEF1NWFiVFViMlk/view?usp=sharing
libstdc++44-dev https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNWHB3ejd0TTNhUWc/view?usp=sharing

Install : Download the three packages, and ...

```
1) sudo apt-get install libgmp3c2
cd Downloads/
2) sudo gdebi gcc44_4.4.7-2_i386.deb
3) sudo gdebi libstdc++44-devel_4.4.7-2_i386.deb
4) sudo gdebi gcc44-c++_4.4.7-2_i386.deb
```

Note : Please advise, if your OS is amd64/x86_64, and 64bits packages can be uploaded.

---

---

If you really want to build gcc-4.4.7 manually : External mpfr, gmp is not required :

```
tar xvf gcc-4.4.7.tar.bz2 (A configured gcc cannot be reused, please start from scratch)
cd gcc-4.4.7/
tar xvf mpfr-2.4.2.tar.bz2
mv -v mpfr-2.4.2 mpfr
tar xvf gmp-5.0.0.tar.bz2
mv -v gmp-5.0.0 gmp
```

gcc requires a build folder outside the source ....

```
cd ../
mkdir build-gcc44
cd build-gcc44/
../gcc-4.4.7/configure --program-suffix=44 --prefix=/usr/local/gcc447 --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib

make
sudo make install
cd /usr/bin/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/gcc447/bin/gcc44
sudo ln -s /usr/local/gcc447/bin/g++44
```

Using an extra compiler, examples :

```
1) export CC=gcc44 CXX=g++44 && [other command]
Like : 2) export CC=gcc44 CXX=g++44 && ./configure
3) gcc44 file.c
```

---

Comment: Are the packages that you have given part of the official Ubuntu distribution ? Because I did not find them on the Ubuntu site. How can I verify that they are un tampered ? also I tried downloading the gcc4.4 from here [http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.4/gcc-4.4_4.4.7-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb]. But it didn't work since the dependencies are not met. Just tell me how I can install a more recent version of MPFR and have gcc link to that.

Comment: MPFR is required for building gcc4.4 just download the gcc4.4.0 sources and check the perquisites.html file.

Comment: My OS is x86_64

Comment: OK, amd64 packages were created .... see my edited post ...

Comment: Why can't a configured gcc be reused ? I don't understand. Could you please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

---

> My OS is x86_64

Packages.amd64 : g++44_4.4.7-ubuntu8_amd64.deb, gcc44_4-4-7-ubuntu8_amd64.deb, libstdc++44-dev_4.4.7-ubuntu8_amd64.deb, created with $ `dpkg-deb -b`

Links : gcc44 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNQlVHeXdPc25sSEE/view?usp=sharing
g++44 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNeU5jSG9ZdXNQQTQ/view?usp=sharing
libstdc++44-dev https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbWxGNEM0TG93LW8/view?usp=sharing

```
1) sudo gdebi libstdc++44-dev_4.4.7-ubuntu8_amd64.deb
2) sudo gdebi gcc44_4-4-7-ubuntu8_amd64.deb
3) sudo gdebi g++44_4.4.7-ubuntu8_amd64.deb
```

The compilers were tested in Hardy with a ~150GB application, hundreds of c, c++ files : Result = OK.

---

---

> MPFR is required for building gcc4.4

Of course. See my post. mpfr is unpacked inside gcc-4.4.7/.

> How can I verify that they are un tampered ?

The many packages I have built over the years have been OK so far. No complaints from any users.

Today´s packages are handled with the Ubuntu Hardy´s alien command : Saves a few minutes.  Instead of a real rebuild with ....

```
$ dpkg-deb -b packagename packagename_version_architecture.deb
```

The three converted packages are from the CentOS 5.11 repo http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.11/os/i386/CentOS/ , i.e "Enterprise quality".

---

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and want to remove old version of mpfr ( libmpfr4).

Solution

- sudo apt-get remove libmpfr4
- manually remove symlinks to old library from usr/local/lib